# how to read csv file using pandas in a docker container

Tags: python, docker

I tried to dockerize my machine learning model written in python. The python script includes using pandas to load csv files. When I ran the image in a container, the `pd.read_csv("FILENAME.csv")`command can't retrieve the csv file,(I think the problem might be that the csv file is not in the container). Any suggestions on what should I do to run this python script and read the csv files on docker.

dockerfile:

```
FROM python:latest
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install sklearn 
COPY . /app
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app/model1.py","death_clean.csv","condition_data_clean.csv"]
```

model1.py

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df1=pd.read_csv("/Users/yaoyan/Desktop/docker-trial/condition_data_clean.csv",error_bad_lines=False)
df2=pd.read_csv("/Users/yaoyan/Desktop/docker-trial/death_clean.csv",error_bad_lines=False)

df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['person_id'], how='left')
```

when I ran it, I got this error:

> FileNotFoundError: File b'/Users/yaoyan/Desktop/docker-trial/condition_data_clean.csv' does not exist

Comment: in pd.read_csv can what if you only used the file name instead of the full path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a volume containing your data using `docker volume` command. After this step you need to mount this storage using `-v` option in `docker run`, e.g. `-v my_data_volum:/data`. Lastly, change your path appropriately in Python script, in this case it would be `/data/my_csv.csv`. More informations in [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Or if you insist on copying the file, use path `/app/condition_data_clean.csv` in your pandas' `read_csv` function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got confused. Should I create the volume in dockerfile by using VOLUME or in command line? and what's the difference. I am a newbie to docker. Any help you offered is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Volume as standalone (e.g. from command line), this way you can easily switch your data by providing different volumes.

Comment: hi, I need help with the same issue, and I started using Docker literally today. `docker volume create my_vol` and then `docker run -v my_vol:/dataset` to mount data folder to volume? however this requires 1 argument...any help would be so appreciated!!

Comment: Your docker run needs an image argument from which you create your container

Comment: I'm really new...do I need to create an image? what does this look like? I'm looking online as well...

Comment: Please check Dockers documentation. Yes, you need an image (usually downloaded from DockerHub) to create a container, you can find more info over there

Comment: Hi @SzymonMaszke , I left a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77877528/reading-local-csv-file-using-docker-compose) but using docker-compose.yml and running `docker-compose up --build`. Do you happen have an idea what I'm doing wrong there? Thanks in advance for your help!