# Reading local csv file using docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `test.csv` file saved in the same root directory as the `DockerFile` and `docker-compose.yml`. I want to read the `test.csv` file in `prepare.py`. However, when I try to read the csv file, it throws a `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/test.csv'` error. I'm running `docker-compose up --build` to build image and run the container. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is what my directory looks like:

```
root
| model
| ---- prepare.py
| DockerFile
| docker-compose.yml
| docker-entrypoint.sh
| test.csv
| Pipfile
| .env
```

**prepare.py**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/app/ranger_trainig_data.csv")
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  testimage:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        args: 
            - PIP_INDEX_URL=${PIP_INDEX_URL}
    image: training_image
    platform: linux/amd64
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
        - .:/app
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.7-buster

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        gnupg \
        libglib2.0-0\
        libxext6 \
        libsm6 \
        libxrender1 \
        build-essential \
        apt-transport-https \
        rsyslog \
        logrotate \
        unixodbc \
        unixodbc-dev


ARG PIP_INDEX_URL
ENV PIP_INDEX_URL=$PIP_INDEX_URL
COPY Pipfile .
RUN python3 -m pip install pipenv
RUN PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1 PIPENV_NOSPIN=1 pipenv install --skip-lock
RUN pipenv graph

WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY model/ model
COPY prepare.py .

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

source /.venv/bin/activate

cd /usr/src
#pipenv run python prepare.py
python3 prepare.py

exec sleep infinity
```

Comment: You don't `COPY` the file into the image, so it's not there.  You're mounting the current directory into a different place in the container filesystem; possibly mounting a more specific file into a more specific place into the container would help, if you don't want to include the input file in the container (`volumes: [./input:/usr/src/input]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working setup to get you started. I don't know what your CSV file contains, but I created some dummy data (8210 records).

A slightly enhanced version of your `prepare.py`.

```py
import pandas as pd

print("Load CSV.")
df = pd.read_csv("/app/ranger_trainig_data.csv")
print(f"CSV file has {df.shape[0]} rows.")
```

The `Dockerfile`. I don't know what your `docker-entrypoint.sh` contains, so I'm just running `prepare.py`.

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.7-buster

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        gnupg \
        libglib2.0-0\
        libxext6 \
        libsm6 \
        libxrender1 \
        build-essential \
        apt-transport-https \
        rsyslog \
        logrotate \
        unixodbc \
        unixodbc-dev

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY prepare.py .

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "prepare.py"]
```

Contents of `requirements.txt`.

```
pandas==1.3.5
```

And finally bringing it all together with `docker-compose.yml`.

```
services:
  testimage:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: training_image
    platform: linux/amd64
    volumes:
        - .:/app
```

Now build and run.

```bash
docker-compose build && docker-compose up
```

[image]